# Mail Delivery System and GMAIL error

Tags: php, email, postfix

After following the following tutorial:

http://blog.seeit.org/2010/08/php-mail-with-ubuntu-desktop-and-gmail/

in order to send email through Gmail.

I get the following error:

```
Mail Delivery System MAILER-DAEMON@

12:38 AM (20 hours ago)

to me
This is the mail system at host .

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to <postmaster>

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

               The mail system

<root@smartlab.cs.ucy.ac.cy> (expanded from <"root@domain>):
delivery temporarily suspended: connect to
domain[IP]: No route to host

Final-Recipient: rfc822; root@domain
Original-Recipient: rfc822;root@domain
Action: failed
Status: 4.4.1
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; delivery temporarily suspended: connect to
domain[IP]: No route to host


---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: root <username@gmail.com>
To: root
Cc: 
Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2012 00:20:01 +0300
Subject: Cron <smmsp@machine> test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail &&    /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
/usr/share/sendmail/sendmail: 1267: /usr/sbin/sendmail-msp: not found
```

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: `root@domain` looks wrong.  You have a FQDN set?

Answer (score 0):

When the `domain[IP]: No route to host` error is mentioned in your submitted error report, I think this means that the host is unavailable. I am not a pro, but I think that probably suggests that the mail server is down, so I should try resending it.

Comment: I get this message continuously every some hours.

Comment: @ntenisOT I know what's wrong. **delivery temporarily suspended**: connect to
domain[IP]: No route to host

There isn't any issue that can be fixed by you. The recipient's mail server has suspended delivery.

Comment: Like it said, try sending a mail to postmaster. Postmaster's address should be postmaster@domain (I do not know the domain)